# Find functions for Union, Substract, Intersect on a List

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

Assume I have tow lists: `List<int> l1,`and`List<int>l2`

Please help me how to to union, substract and intersect between 2 list. Thanks.

Note: I am using .NET 2.0, so I can't use LINQ. Thanks.

Comment: Could you at least tell us what you've tried, and where you've gotten stuck?

Comment: How about using List<T>, and use the Contains() method? It should solve all your problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ - just not the LINQ from .NET 3.5. You can use [LINQBridge](http://linqbridge.googlecode.com) though, or if you *really* just want `Union` / `Except` / `Intersect` you could look at the source for [Edulinq](http://edulinq.googlecode.com) (my own implementation of LINQ to Objects). The latter uses `HashSet<T>` which is only in .NET 3.5, but you could use a `Dictionary<,>` to fake that.

The problem with using `List<T>.Contains` repeatedly is that *each* `Contains` operation is O(N). That's okay if you've got a small amount of data or if you just want this code to see the principle of the three operations, but for "real" work you'd want a more efficient contains check.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the basic algorithms as pseudo-code:

```
UNION:
    Copy List1 to UnionList
    For each Item in List2
        If Item is not in UnionList 
            Add Item to UnionList
    Next
    Return UnionList

SUBTRACT:
    Copy List1 to DifferenceList
    For each Item in List2
        If Item is in DifferenceList
            Remove Item from DifferenceList
    Next
    Return DifferenceList

INTERSECT:
    Create new IntersectList
    For Each Item in List1
        If Item is in List2
            Add Item to IntersectList
    Next
    Return IntersectList
```